# Multiple tables update MVC .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new to MVC and this is my function. There are three tables (Order, OrderNotes, Notes), ID is their primary key. One Order can have many Notes, the table OrderNotes has foreign key OrderID(from Booking table) and NotesID(from Notes table). I want to have a Order Edit page to display individual Order (FirstName, LastName), also display a list of its Notes. Here is my DB structure:

1. Booking table:
   {ID,
   FirstName,
   LastName
   }
2. BookingNotes table:
   {ID,
   BookingID,
   NotesID
   }
3. Notes table:
   {ID,
   NoteName,
   StatusID
   }

So how can I implement the list of Notes since it's from multiple tables? It will be able to **Create** New Note, **Delete** existing Note in the list row record, not Edit. Linq used in DB query. Thanks.

Comment: Please show some code to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a better idea to have only 2 tables:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // Navigational properties
    public virtual List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Note
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string NoteName { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }

    // Navigational properties
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

A third table is useful when you want to reuse the same `Note` for a different booking. However i think this is not the case.

So to retrieve data for your context make sure you have the `DbSet<Book>`

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Book> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller (or better in a repository class):

```
var BookingID = 10; // this is parameter passed to the function
var myBooking = this.dbContext.Bookings
    .Include(p => p.Notes)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.Status)
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == BookingID);
```

Map the retrieved booking to a `ViewModel`, pass it to the View and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks very much Cristian, it's working in this way.